# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class ..." in spring-native image when entity not in same package hierarchy as app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-native

I have a spring-boot app with spring-data-jpa and spring-native. When running the native image I get the "Not a managed type" exception on my Entity when my Entity class is not in the same package hierarchy as the application class, even though I've specified the package where the Entity is in the @EntityScan annotation.  The app starts up and works fine in JVM mode.  It also starts up and works fine in the native image when I move the Entity class to a sub-package of the application class.  But this is not always possible (or even desirable).  Is this a spring-native bug?